# Javascript multi-lined variable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is for a multi-lined variable in AJax Chat which is being set what I'm trying to do is add an image before other things are set. However it is always putting the image and text on separate lines when it's displayed. I do not think it's a problem to do with the variable more the container it is displayed in.

Placing html image tag before the ahref tag is causing the problem and even at the end of it. I may have to look into the size of the container of that div possibly?

Heres some of the code

```
encodedUserName = this.scriptLinkEncode(userName);
        str = '<div id="'
                + this.getUserDocumentID(userID)
                + '"><a href="javascript:ajaxChat.toggleUserMenu(\''
                + this.getUserMenuDocumentID(userID)
                + '\', \''
                + encodedUserName
                + '\', '
                + userID
                + ');" class="'
                + this.getRoleClass(userRole)
                + '" title="'
                + this.lang['toggleUserMenu'].replace(/%s/, userName)
                + '">'
                + userName
                + '</a>'
                + '<ul class="userMenu" id="'
                + this.getUserMenuDocumentID(userID)
                + '"'
                + ((userID === this.userID) ?
                    '>'+this.getUserNodeStringItems(encodedUserName, userID, false) :
                    ' style="display:none;">')
                + '</ul>'
                +'</div>';
        if(userID === this.userID) {
            this.userNodeString = str;
        }
        return str;
```

Thank you all.

Comment: If you're having style problems, then you need to look at the HTML you're generating and adjust your CSS to fix it.

Comment: it possibly is but there is no style attached to that div.

The list it makes in the UL tags take up more width than the image and the text so i don't really think it's anything to do with css.

Comment: So? Basic semantics of HTML elements and CSS determine how they're rendered. Put your image wherever it makes sense to then modify your CSS to style it correctly. It doesn't matter if no styles are attached to it at the moment. CSS has *everything* to do with how things are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The CSS was using display:block so I changed it :)

Thank you all.